# Accessing user defined delegate via multiple ViewControllers - iOS

Tags: ios, delegates, protocols

I'm using the BLE framework files that came with some hardware, but I'm only able to call the functions in my first view controller.  My application has two view controllers and it is my intention to write and read BLE data in both views, using the BLEDelegate.

Everything works as expected in the first view controller, but I get no action from the BLE files in the second view controller.

This is a skeleton of my project.

BLE.h

```
#import <CoreBluetooth/CoreBluetooth.h>
@protocol BLEDelegate
@optional
-(void) bleDidReceiveData:(unsigned char *) data length:(int) length;
@required
@end
@interface BLE : NSObject;
@property (nonatomic,assign) id <BLEDelegate> delegate;
-(void) write:(NSData *)d;
@end
```

BLE.m

```
#import "BLE.h"
@interface BLE ()
@end
@implementation BLE
@synthesize delegate;
-(void) write:(NSData *)d
{
//send BLE packet
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes: &d length: sizeof(d)];
NSLog(@"%@", data);
}
@end
```

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "BLE.h"
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<BLEDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) BLE *ble;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btnClicked;
@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "SecondViewController.h"
@interface ViewController ()
@end
@implementation ViewController
@synthesize ble;
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  ble = [[BLE alloc] init];
  ble.delegate = self;
}
-(void)bleDidReceiveData:(unsigned char *)data length:(int)length
{
  //parse data
}
- (IBAction)btnClicked:(id)sender
{
  uint32_t packet = 0xFFFF;
  NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes: &packet length: sizeof(packet)];
  [ble write:data];
}
@end
```

SecondViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "BLE.h"
@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController<BLEDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) BLE *ble;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btnClicked;
@end
```

SecondViewController.m

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"
#import "ViewController.h"
@interface SecondViewController ()
@end
@implementation SecondViewController
@synthesize ble;
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  ble = [[BLE alloc] init];
  ble.delegate = self;
}
-(void)bleDidReceiveData:(unsigned char *)data length:(int)length
{
  //parse data
}
- (IBAction)btnClicked:(id)sender
{
  uint32_t packet = 0xFFFF;
  NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes: &packet length: sizeof(packet)];
  [ble write:data];
}
@end
```

Comment: You really only want to have a single instance of your BLE manager, rather than one per view controller, as  the second one won't be connected to your peripheral.  A delegate pattern doesn't really work in this case since you can only have a single delegate.  I would suggest you hold your BLE class on your app delegate and have it use NSNotifications rather than delegate to communicate with your view controllers

Comment: Could I use the write and receive methods from the the BLE class with NSNotifications?

Comment: Yes, well certainly for receive.  The delegate methods in the BLE class would post an NSNotification when data was received.  For write, the view controller would just call write on the BLE class instance it obtained from the app delegate